# Visual Studio 2017 Community button size greater than images in image list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, tablelayoutpanel, imagelist

I'm trying to precisely align an array of buttons within the rows and columns of a table layout panel.  Each button is assigned to the same image list.  The image list contains three images, all the same pixel dimensions (200px wide X 18px high).  I want the buttons to exactly stack one on top of one another vertically, with no vertical gaps.

The problem is, when I look at the button properties, the size of the image is described as 206x24.  It looks like somewhere VS is adding a 3 pixel boundary around the images, and I can't figure out how to get rid of that.

Margins for the button are all set to zero.  Padding for the button is all set to zero.  FlatStyle is set to "Flat".

What button properties do I set to get the images to stack exactly?
Is there a parameter in the table layout panel that might be causing this?

Here is an image of the button property box:

[Image of property box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUd2C.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.
Would using a picturebox with a clickable change of image work better than a button?

Answer (score 0):

You've only talked about your button styling.  Look at padding and margins for your table elements, such as TD, TR, etc.  A quick way to see this visually is to add colors for these elements in css.  If you make a TD red and see a 3 pixel red space, you've got your culprit.  Try this with ANY elements that are in your markup.  ANYTHING could be a culprit.

BTW, I've noticed a downvote on your post.  I think folks here appreciate if you post your code so they can see what you've tried so far.  Just a friendly reminder.

Comment: Thank you for the response about lack of detail.  I added an image showing the properties of the button in VS designer.  It's a windows forms application.  If I can't get this to work, I will switch to a picturebox with an event handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

I continued researching the best way to handle the look I was going for, and others that have tried to use buttons, and had similar problems.  I have abandoned the button, and will use a picturebox instead in each of the cells of the table view control.

My apologies for the imprecise question.